# Modify External .config without <configuration> tag

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="_config\ConnStr.config"/>
</configuration>
```

and ConnStr.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=sa;Password=password"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I open ConnStr.config using ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = filePath;
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, level);
```

it throws an exception: "ConnStr.config does not have root `<configuration>` tag"

I can't add  tag in ConnStr.config, because if I add it, it will throw an exception: "The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the name of the section"

So, how to open external configuration files without `<configuration>` tag?

Comment: Why don't you just read ConnStr as an xml? Why bother with the config manager for that file?

Comment: @Alex: It works, I think XMLDocument only works for .xml files, thank you

Comment: You can use .Parse() method to read any xml string.